# jQuery display wordpress categories by click of category buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

So i'm making reference page where top of the page i have these category buttons:

All | refe 1 | refe 2 | refe 3 | refe 4 | ect..

After buttons i have field that displays all references. I need to do this page so that if you click on category its shows the category and you should be able to click multiple categories, so it need to be on same page.

Top buttons are automated so it will show all the terms automatically and buttons have class of the term. In the display field references has the same class that the button. Can you help me?

---

Edit:

Here is the code for now (i have only made it so if you click button all it show all and does the animation for the button):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.all').on('click', function(){
        $('.hidden-box').toggle();
            $(this).toggleClass("down");
    });
```

});

Comment: And where is code you have tried so far ?

Comment: Added now, havent got far, i suck with jquery